# Can't add javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html

I tried a very simple code with JavaScript and I can't understand why it doesn't work...
 I have already seen the tip of putting the `<script>` tag just before the `<body/>` end tag but it doesn't fix the problem.
 Here are my HTML and js files:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> popup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><button id="submit"> send</button></div>
    <p id = "test">hello</p>


    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
 var button = document.getElementById("submit");

 button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML() = "hey"
   
 })
})
```

Comment: Where is your `test.js` file located in relation to your html file? The problem might be in the src attribute of your script tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`innerHTML` is not a function but a property... try the following
`document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "hey"`

Comment: Thank you @fedeghe !

Comment: @Biflame3008 u’r welcome